# tqdm is not continuing its progress and starts from anew

Tags: python, deep-learning, printing, tqdm

I have the following working code.
I would like to print all the 5000th item's loss each one (% 5000) on a new line **but the progress bar should continue
its way once and for all (should be printed once only)** and show the total progress. How should I modify the code?

```
import torch
from math import tanh,cos
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

batch, dim_in, dim_h, dim_out = 1, 100, 10, 1

input_X = torch.randn(batch, dim_in)
output_Y = torch.randn(batch, dim_out)

SGD_model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(dim_in, dim_h),
    torch.nn.Tanh(),
    torch.nn.Linear(dim_h, dim_out),
)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

rate_learning = 0.01

optim = torch.optim.SGD(SGD_model.parameters(), lr=rate_learning, momentum=0.01)
    
for values in tqdm(range(1000)):
    pred_y = SGD_model(input_X)
    loss = loss_fn(pred_y, output_Y)
    if values % 100 == 0:
        print(values, loss.item())  
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

Three progress bars instead of one:

[image]

[image]

chatGPT 4 offered me this code, but still there are 4 progress bars:

```
import torch
from math import tanh
from time import sleep

batch, dim_in, dim_h, dim_out = 32, 10, 5, 1

input_X = torch.randn(batch, dim_in)
output_Y = torch.randn(batch, dim_out)

SGD_model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(dim_in, dim_h),
    torch.nn.Tanh(),
    torch.nn.Linear(dim_h, dim_out),
)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

rate_learning = 0.0001

optim = torch.optim.SGD(SGD_model.parameters(), lr=rate_learning, momentum=0.4)

# Define the training loop with a range
epochs = 1000
for epoch in range(epochs):
    progress = (epoch + 1) / epochs
    bar_length = 50
    block = int(round(bar_length * progress))
    text = f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs} [{'#' * block + '-' * (bar_length - block)}] {100 * progress:.2f}%"
    pred_y = SGD_model(input_X)
    loss = loss_fn(pred_y, output_Y)
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        text += f', Loss: {loss.item()}'
    print(text, end='\r')
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()

print("\nWeights:", SGD_model[0].weight)
print("Bias:", SGD_model[0].bias)
print("Bias:", SGD_model[2].bias)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `print( ... )`, prefer `tqdm.write( ... )`.

Also, consider replacing prints with a
[logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).
Then you can rely on a tqdm
[context manager](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#redirecting-logging).
From the docs:

```
    with logging_redirect_tqdm():
        for i in trange(9):
            if i == 4:
                LOG.info("console logging redirected to `tqdm.write()`")
```

As a context diff to your original code, "use .write()!" boils down to:

```
@@ -85,3 +85,3 @@ for values in tqdm(range(1000)):
     if values % 100 == 0:
-        print(values, loss.item())
+        tqdm.write(f"{values}, {loss.item()}")
     optim.zero_grad()
```

Additionally, if you start out the loop with a bound progress bar variable

```
bar = tqdm(range(1000))
for values in bar:
```

you can use `bar.write( ... )` within the loop.
Or better you might `bar.set_description( ... )`
or adjust `bar.bar_format`.
That prevents old loss figures from scrolling off top-of-screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I'm still getting error messages: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'write'` Could you modify my code in your answer so that I do not get errors ? And of course **one** progress bar only as required.

Comment: You said `print(values)` to display a `float` quantity, and print() is good with that. But [.write()](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#write) is a little less flexible, and expects you to hand in a `str`. Use `tqdm.write(f'{values}')`. Or go with the logger approach that I recommended.

Comment: Currently I do not wish to use `logger`. But your `tqdm.write(f'{values}')` still prints several progress bars. I'm struggling with this issue for a few days, could you kindly provide me with a working version of my code that prints only one progress bar ? See also my **EDIT** for `tqdm.write`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten) instead of tqdm since it handles printing natively.

You also have an off-by-one issue with `range()` since you're going from 0 to 999 rather than 1 to 1000.

Just replace

```py
for values in tqdm(range(1000)):
```

with

```py
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=1000)

for values in pbar(range(1, 1001)):
```

You'll get something like this. No need to do anything special with your output.

```
100 2.220446049250313e-16
200 2.220446049250313e-16
300 2.220446049250313e-16
400 2.220446049250313e-16
500 2.220446049250313e-16
600 2.220446049250313e-16
700 2.220446049250313e-16
800 2.220446049250313e-16
900 2.220446049250313e-16
1000 2.220446049250313e-16

100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 8639.66/s]
```

If you want to customize the format or add color, take a look at the [documentation](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).